# How to add a zero before numbers in WordPress Post Pagination?

Tags: pagination, codex

I want my POST pagination to show the numbers from 1 to 9 like this:
01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 10 11... and NOT like > 1, 2, 3, 4...

Actualy i have this code:

```
<?php wp_link_pages( array( 'before' => '
<div class="page-links clr">', 'after' => '</div>

', 'link_before' => '<span>', 'link_after' => '</span>' ) );?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`wp_link_pages()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_link_pages) does not have a parameter for what you want. So I'm thinking you can make use of the filter hook [`wp_link_pages_link`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_link_pages_link/), which has two - `$link` and `$i` - parameters, where `$i` is the page number. You can use WordPress' [`zeroise()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/zeroise) function to get the format you want.

Answer (score 0):

Simple replace content in `<a></a>`

```
function custom_pagination(){

    global $wp_query;
    $max_pages    = $wp_query->max_num_pages;
    $current_page = !empty($wp_query->query_vars['paged']) ? $wp_query->query_vars['paged'] : 1;

?>
    <nav class="pagination">
<?php
        $big = 999999999;
$paginate_links = paginate_links(array(...));

$paterns = ['/\>1\<\//', '/\>2\<\//','/\>3\<\//','/\>4\<\//','/\>5\<\//','/\>6\<\//', '/\>7\<\//','/\>8\<\//','/\>9\<\//'];
        $replacements = ['>01</', '>02</', '>03</', '>04</', '>05</', '>06</','>07</', '>08</', '>09</'];
        $paginate_links = preg_replace( $paterns, $replacements, $paginate_links );

if ( $paginate_links ) {
    foreach( $paginate_links as $link )
        echo $link;
}

?>
    </nav>
<?php
}
```